# Angular JS use ng-show to hide certain options of Jquery Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to hide certain options of the multiselect based on certain condition. I tried to replicate the scenario please see : http://plnkr.co/edit/7cSr5eQYlti4MHGCBa3q?p=preview

```
<select id="nameType"
            ng-model="selectChoice"
            multiple="multiple"
            name="example-basic"
            size="4"
            style="width:225px">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3" ng-show="visible">Option3</option>
    <option value="Option4" ng-show="visible">Option4</option>
    <option value="Option5" ng-show="visible">Option5</option>
</select>
<button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle </button>

function MainController ($scope) {
    $scope.visible = true;
    $scope.toggle = toggle;

    function toggle () {
        console.log("hiding options");
        if ($scope.visible === false) {
          $scope.visible = true;
        }else {
          $scope.visible = false;
        }
}
```

}

Expected: option3,4,5 should be hidden... I know one option is not to use Jquery and Angular JS together, but this code is already in production and can't be easily changed. Is it possible to make it work? I have a feeling $scope.$apply() is the solution but could not make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this kind of hacky solution:

Change the `ng-show`s to `ng-if`s to ensure they are taken out of the DOM when we toggle the visibility:

```
<select id="nameType"
        ng-model="selectChoice"
        multiple="multiple"
        name="example-basic"
        size="4"
        style="width:225px">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="Option3" ng-if="visible">Option3</option>
    <option value="Option4" ng-if="visible">Option4</option>
    <option value="Option5" ng-if="visible">Option5</option>
</select>
```

And then in your `MainController` inject `$timeout` and change it to the following:

```
(function (angular){
    angular.module("main-app", [])
           .controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$timeout", MainController]);

    function MainController($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.visible = true;
        $scope.toggle = toggle;

        function toggle () {
            console.log("hiding options");
            $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
            refreshMultiSelect();
        }

        function refreshMultiSelect() {
            $timeout(function() {
                $("select").multiselect("refresh");
            }, 0);
        }
    }
})(window.angular);
```

Using the `refresh` [method](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget#methods) of the multiselect we redraw the control now with the updated options. Because I used `ng-if` the `option` elements where `visible` is false are not in the DOM and the `refresh` won't put those into the dropdown.

Working Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vpspk0TA4MAIuyxW2wrC?p=preview).